# New mvc controller object on each httppost?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, http-post

Thanks for your time!

I'm creating an MVC web app and use HttpPost to request data from web-page. Debugging my app I noticed that each time an HttpPost comes back a new controller object is created (a controller constructor is called). Is it possible to use the same object each time as HttpPost comes?

The code:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    private Data data;

    public HomeController()
    {
        // something here - it is called on each HttpPost comes
        // initializing data
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateData(FormCollection collection)
    {
        // simply returning JSON string
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but you shouldn't. It goes against the whole concept of the framework and the web. Now, if you're building a web app and need to store some (user) data, consider persisting it either in the database or in the `Session`.

Comment: The question that will be asked is, Why? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks, guys! I'm trying to save some time on opening a connection to sql database. If a new controller object is created on each httppost it means that a new connection to db is established. I'd like to save some time on opening and closing a new connection each time. Is there another way?